# The difference between "common" and "commonly"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

The adjective "common" has the meaning of "shared by". 
Does the adverb "commonly" have such a meaning?

For example, does the sentence below I created make sense? I am trying to describe that each bulb is supplied with the same voltage of 120 volts.

> A voltage of 120 volts is applied commonly to three bulbs.

[image]

Comment: I'd say **evenly between**. But 60+60+60 makes 180 and not 120 unless I understood you wrongly.

Comment: @SovereignSun  Haha, it's 120 volts, not 120 watts.  Nothing is being added.  120 volts are applied to each of the 60 watt bulbs.

Comment: @farnsy Missed that one. Well, say, "**A voltage of 120 volts is applied to each of the three bulbs**"

Comment: No dictionary lists this meaning of *commonly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper example of the word `commonly` would be:

```
Lightbulbs commonly burn out after 500 hours of use.
```

In the example you give, I might use `equally`  as in

```
A voltage of 120 volts is applied equally to three bulbs.
```

or

```
A voltage of 120 volts is equally applied to three bulbs.
```

The two sentences mean essentially the same thing.